# Phonegap plugins for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

When using "phonegap" on a windows machine (haven't tried it on mac) and building a "phonegap" project for android, all plugins are copied into the src directory, and you can edit the plugin files while your android project is open in your java ide.

I have tried to now build my project on a MacBook, using "phonegap 3.4".  I have created the project, added my plugins (camera, splashscreen) and then built the project. Now i am guessing that the `.h` and `.m` files should be copied into the plugins folder within your xcode project. But there are not there?

The `config.xml` file references each plugin, but i cannot see the actual plugin `.h` and `.m` code.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You Should See the Plugin Source code in youproject/plugins/
or after adding platform and build  youproject/platform/ios/youproject/plugin

Comment: What do u mean by both paths?

Comment: Using phonegap plugin add <path to plugin>. Tried camera and sqlite plugin via github. Both work on windows machine installing for android

Comment: manual add should let you see plugin src but idon't know if you can modify  it through Xcode  on mac but when you add plugin should show up in urproject/plugins/